# How to I get something specific out of this block?

Tags: python, list

So I have this block of information in one list class. Whenever I do print(block) it loops through the entire list and outputs following:

> [{'version': 3,   'from':
>   'hx7ccc54932b913c71f7051e9dc1b621074c91d462',  'to':
>   'hxbf2a3504318b6315e38eeb87ee84402361a7d644',   'stepLimit': 1000000, 
>   'timestamp': 1547599428802897,  'nid': 1,   'value':
>   30000000000000000000000,  'signature':
>   'ehslHJOj5e6apGhxEbZ6SESx5fagazIPNI5BjCo3sMYAGWVMQbiN8w/PH8BHhHmXBtwEGWiqEuTU5fa4toeOvwE=',
>   'txHash':
>   '0x833bf64c224209ce850df8f9d47b9b6fcb1471cee93d8c946c2a2bfbded3fb2a'}]

I have tried to do print(block[1]) as well as print(block[0][1]) but it says out of range?

```
from iconsdk.icon_service import IconService
from iconsdk.providers.http_provider import HTTPProvider

def main():
    icon_service = IconService(HTTPProvider("https://ctz.solidwallet.io/api/v3"))
    block = icon_service.get_block("latest")['confirmed_transaction_list']
    print(block)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expect it to give me the result of 'to' (hxbf2a3504318b6315e38eeb87ee84402361a7d644) instead of looping through the entire block even though i never told the program to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, get the key and print it:

```
from iconsdk.icon_service import IconService
from iconsdk.providers.http_provider import HTTPProvider

def main():
    icon_service = IconService(HTTPProvider("https://ctz.solidwallet.io/api/v3"))
    block = icon_service.get_block("latest")['confirmed_transaction_list']
    print(block[0]['to'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then it will work.

Comment: Hmm i got this:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adam/PycharmProjects/icxhawk/iconhawk.py", line 18, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/adam/PycharmProjects/icxhawk/iconhawk.py", line 14, in main
    print(block[1][['to']])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @AdamPalmkvist No. copy my whole code again, it will work, the problem there was that you made the line `print(block[0]['to'])` into `print(block[1]['to'])`

Comment: oh i'm dumb... Thanks so much!

Comment: @AdamPalmkvist Your welcome, don't forget to accept and up-vote if it works.

Comment: Yeah there is a 10 min timer before i can do the accept thing